Can Knuth's "Algorithm B" be written without goto statements or recursion?
Though I've already implemented the basic recursive N queens solution, I'm trying to learn more about backtracking by studying and implementing Knuth's "Algorithm B (Basic backtrack)" for the case of the N queens problem in C. If you want to read it, it's here (https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5b.ps.gz). This is the code I have written so far, and it works well. It's a straightforward translation of what he wrote into C using goto statements (with a few parts changed to account for zero-indexed arrays instead of one-indexed arrays).
// x and a are both N elements long, while b and c are 2*N-1 elements long.
// It is assumed that these arrays are zeroed before this routine is called.
static void queens(int x[], bool a[], bool b[], bool c[], const size_t n) {
    size_t col, row = 0;

advance_row:
    if (row >= n) {
        // e.g. print "a2 b4 c1 d3" if n is 4
        print_positions(x, n);
        goto backtrack;
    }
    col = 0;
try_column:
    if (!a[col] && !b[col+row-1] && !c[col-row+n]) {
        a[col] = true;
        b[col+row-1] = true;
        c[col-row+n] = true;
        x[row] = col;
        row++;
        goto advance_row;
    }
try_again:
    if (col < n-1) {
        col++;
        goto try_column;
    }
backtrack:
    if (row != 0) {
        --row;
        col = x[row];
        c[col-row+n] = false;
        b[col+row-1] = false;
        a[col] = false;
        goto try_again;
    }
}

From what I can tell, this algorithm has an irreducible control flow graph (CFG). I drew a CFG of Algorithm B to illustrate below. Because of this, I expect it to be impossible to implement using just while-loops, for-loops, and if-statements, though I have tried. I expect that some state will need to be kept in a variable, but I don't know how to represent this graph like that.

What I've tried and what happened: although I haven't written any versions without the use of the goto statement, I have tried to replace the use of a couple goto statements in this code. This is one of the versions of the function I have made, but note that it is incorrect; for n = 4, it prints the first 2 solutions correctly, but prints 58 more incorrect solutions.
static void queens(int x[], bool a[], bool b[], bool c[], const size_t n) {
    for (size_t row = 0, col = 0; ; col++) {
        while (!a[col] && !b[col+row-1] && !c[col-row+n]) {
            a[col] = true;
            b[col+row-1] = true;
            c[col-row+n] = true;
            x[row] = col;
            row++;
            if (row >= n) {
                print_positions(x, n);
                goto backtrack;
            }
            col = 0;
        }
        if (col < n - 1) {
            continue;
        }
    backtrack:
        if (row == 0) break;
        else do {
            --row;
            col = x[row];
            c[col-row+n] = false;
            b[col+row-1] = false;
            a[col] = false;
            if (col < n - 1) {
                break;
            }
        } while (row != 0);
    }
}


If it can be written with recursion (which uses the process stack), it can be transformed to a loop + an explicit stack. So the answer is yes, it can be written without recursion, by transforming it into an iterative version using an explicit stack. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration

Here is how you could do it with while loops. The comments indicate where the labelled blocks map to:
static void queens(int x[], bool a[], bool b[], bool c[], const size_t n) {
    size_t col = 0, row = 0;

    while (true) {
        while (row < n && col < n) {
            // try_column:
            while (row < n && !a[col] && !b[col+row-1] && !c[col-row+n]) {
                a[col] = true;
                b[col+row-1] = true;
                c[col-row+n] = true;
                x[row] = col;
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }
            // try_again:
            col++;
        }
        if (row >= n) {
            // e.g. print "a2 b4 c1 d3" if n is 4
            print_positions(x, n);
        }
        // backtrack;
        if (row == 0) return;
        --row;
        col = x[row];
        c[col-row+n] = false;
        b[col+row-1] = false;
        a[col] = false;
        // try_again:
        col++;
    }
}

The col++ code is duplicated. This can be avoided if you define col as a signed integer, initialise it as -1, adapt the middle while condition accordingly and increment col just above the // try_column: comment, and only there.

Thanks, this works. Could you please explain why the test for "col < n - 1" was replaced with "col < n"? I tried replacing the it with the former and it didn't work (i.e. "col < n" is correct), so I guess something about your solution changed the test required. Partly, it's that I don't fully understand the version with goto anyway.

In the original code, col++ is executed after the condition is checked, while here it is executed before the condition. And so the condition has to be different.

By the way, the variable "col" should be initialized to zero, or else it is read without being initialized. I didn't suggest an edit because it would be an edit that's less than 6 characters, so I couldn't add it.

Thanks for spotting that, @MaroonSphinx, I made the update.
